# Tkinter: Problems with tag system - How does it work?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to code a Minesweeper with Tkinter in Python 3. Look at the code for now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from random import *

color = "red"
case=[]
fenetre = Tk()

gamezone_x = 10
gamezone_y = 10
mines = 10

def leftclick(event):
    print("Leftclicked at", event.x, event.y)

def rightclick(event):
    print("Rightclicked at", event.x, event.y)

def mines_gen(mines):
    while(mines>0):
        x=randint(0,9)
        y=randint(0,9)
        print(case[x][y])
        Canvas.config(case[x][y], bg="blue")
        Canvas.addtag(case[x][y], "bomb")
        mines-=1

for x in range(gamezone_x):
    case.append([])
    for y in range(gamezone_y):
        case[x].append(Canvas(fenetre, width=20, heigh=20,bg="red"))
        case[x][y].grid(row=x, column=y)
        case[x][y].bind("<1>", leftclick)
        case[x][y].bind("<3>", rightclick)

mines_gen(mines)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

I can generate my matrix of red canvas and change random canvas in blue. But when I had my "addtag" (in the `mines_gen()` definition, the program doesn't work and said:

```
TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!canvas22 addtag tag searchCommand ?arg ...?"
```

I'm pretty sure that I didn't find how the tags work and how to create/delete/find them and the docs don't help me!

How can I add the tag `"bomb"` to my blue canvas?

Comment: Why are you using tags. For a game like minesweeper you could simply use buttons in a grid.

Comment: In this case, how can I detect where mines are places when I click on the button?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple change to your code that will set random mines.

You cannot call `Canvas()` all the time. All you are doing is creating new canvas each time. Instead you should be calling the canvas object you made in the `case` list. Try the below and let me know if it is what you were attempting to do.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
color = "red"
case = []
fenetre = tk.Tk()

gamezone_x = 10
gamezone_y = 10
mines = 10

def leftclick(event):
    print("Leftclicked at", event.x, event.y)

def rightclick(event):
    print("Rightclicked at", event.x, event.y)

def mines_gen(mines):
    while(mines > 0):
        x=randint(0, 9)
        y=randint(0, 9)
        print(case[x][y])
        case[x][y].config(bg="blue")
        case[x][y].addtag("bomb", "closest", x, y)
        mines -= 1

for x in range(gamezone_x):
    case.append([])
    for y in range(gamezone_y):
        case[x].append(tk.Canvas(fenetre, width=20, heigh=20, bg="red"))
        case[x][y].grid(row=x, column=y)
        case[x][y].bind("<1>", leftclick)
        case[x][y].bind("<3>", rightclick)

mines_gen(mines)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have another question: How can I look if, for example, case[3][4] have the "bomb" tag?

Comment: @Heexos: No objects have a "bomb" tag because the `case[x][y].addtag("bomb", "closest", x, y)` statement doesn't do anything since there aren't any objects on each of the `Canvas` objects in the grid.